# Adding infinite custom field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title explains, I am trying to add infinite custom fields for two things:

1.Name
2.Bio

Now i tried adding 1000 custom fields and upon update it showed me just **471**, There's no way it exceeds and i tried this on my local environment as well as the online but same results

```
// Adding the metaboxes
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_employee_meta' );

    /* Saving the data */
    add_action( 'save_post', 'employee_meta_save' );

    /* Adding the main meta box container to the post editor screen */
    function add_employee_meta() {
        add_meta_box(
            'employee-details',
           'Employee Details',
            'employee_details_init',
            'post');
    }

    /*Printing the box content */
    function employee_details_init() {
        global $post;
        // Use nonce for verification
        wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'employee_nonce' );
        ?>
        <div id="employee_meta_item">
        <?php

        //Obtaining the linked employeedetails meta values
        $employeeDetails = get_post_meta($post->ID,'employeeDetails',true);
        $c = 0;
        if ( count( $employeeDetails ) > 0 && is_array($employeeDetails)) {
            foreach( $employeeDetails as $employeeDetail ) {
                if ( isset( $employeeDetail['name'] ) || isset( $employeeDetail['bio'] ) ) {
                    printf( '<p>Name<input type="text" name="employeeDetails[%1$s][name]" value="%2$s" />  Package : <textarea name="employeeDetails[%1$s][bio]"  rows="4" cols="50" >%3$s</textarea><a href="#" class="remove-package">%4$s</a></p>', $c, $employeeDetail['name'], $employeeDetail['bio'], 'Remove' );
                    $c = $c +1;
                }
            }
        }

        ?>
    <span id="output-package"></span>
    <a href="#" class="add_package"><?php _e('Add Employee Details'); ?></a>
    <script>
        var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
            $(".add_package").click(function() {
                count = count + 1;

                $('#output-package').append('<p> Name <input type="text" name="employeeDetails['+count+'][name]" value="" />  bio : <textarea name="employeeDetails['+count+'][bio]" rows="4" cols="50" ></textarea><a href="#" class="remove-package"><?php echo "Remove"; ?></a></p>' );
                return false;
            });
           $(document.body).on('click','.remove-package',function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </div><?php

    }

    /* Save function for the entered data */
    function employee_meta_save( $post_id ) {
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return;
        // Verifying the nonce
        if ( !isset( $_POST['employee_nonce'] ) )
            return;

        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['employee_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
            return;
        // Updating the employeeDetails meta data
        $employeeDetails = $_POST['employeeDetails'];

        update_post_meta($post_id,'employeeDetails',$employeeDetails);
    }
```

Have anyone tried adding a lot of custom fields and was there such limit as of what i am facing right now ?

Is there any way we can actually use any number of custom fields without this sort of restriction that i am having right now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hard code it without a plugin by adding this to you functions.

```
add_filter( 'postmeta_form_limit' , 'customfield_limit_increase' );
function customfield_limit_increase( $limit ) {
    $limit = 1000;
    return $limit;
}
```

I would think you could possibly end up with a performance issue going overboard with this.

Also you could run into a php limitation even with the ACF plugin mentioned above. (in PHP 5.3.9)  If that is the case you can add this to your .htaccess file...

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
```

Comment: That didn't help, Have you personally tried this before ? As per my knowledge, You can use this function to bypass the default 30 limit placed by wordpress as in this [Core Trac Wordpress](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L556)

Comment: Nope I have never had the need to add that many custom fields.  Sorry if you already had tried that. :(